# Extending (rewriting) both a model/abstract and model/observer in the same config

Tags: event-observer, extensions, configuration, model

I'm trying to extend locally a community extension's `Model/Abstract.php` and `Model/Observer.php` at the same time.

The logs show that with the below local configuration the local observer and community abstract are used. How to change it so the local one is used in both cases?

```
<global>
    <models>
        <Compasser_Diogenes_page>
            <rewrite>
                <abstract>Kaska_Diogenesext_Model_Abstract</abstract>
            </rewrite>
            <rewrite>
                <observer>Kaska_Diogenesext_Model_Observer</observer>
            </rewrite>
        </Compasser_Diogenes_page>
    </models>
```

Comment: please show us `config.xml` file of the community extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **it is not possible to rewrite an Abstract class in Magento**. The only thing that you can do with an abstract class is inherit it's properties by extending that class.

If you really want to overwrite the abstract class of your community extension, then the only way to do this is, place that abstract file in the local codePool. ie copy paste `app\code\community\{ExtensionNamespace}\{ExtensionModule}\Model\Abstract.php` to `app\code\local\{ExtensionNamespace}\{ExtensionModule}\Model\Abstract.php`.

Then edit the method that you want to overwrite. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I've tried the quick-and-dirty way (traditional class override and copy) but it's still just picking up the community version. Is there anything else I need to do apart from copy and paste the file from community to local?

Comment: @kaska that should work in normal case. did u clear cache??

Comment: Actually, I know what you mean now. I was putting the abstract file in my own local extension folder rather than copying the community extension folder structure over. Thanks.